# PHP WebSocket doesn't connect

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet, phpwebsocket

I'm using [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) to create a PHP WebSocket connection. On my `localhost` it's working normally and as expected, but when I upload it to my server it just stops working.

I'm using an online shared hosting and this is the code on the `PHP` file:

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ), 8000, '0.0.0.0'
);
```

And this is my `JS` file

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://mywebsite.com:8000');
```

The only error I got is this:

> Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

**Note**: I've already ran `php server.php` to initiate the ws server via SSH command. I got no errors there but still can't connect. I also tried using different *port* but nothing seems to be working.

---

**Why I'm trying to use WebSockets?**

I have an e-commerce and I'm using the WebSockets to load/update each order without needing to refresh the page and also without using JavaScript Interval, so if an order change from 'Packing..' to 'Delivery' status, the system autoupdate without needing to refresh the page.

If there is another way around this, I'm open to ideas, as long as I can get the final result.

Comment: Is your server behind a firewall which is blocking incoming connections to port 8000?

Comment: @apokryfos Since it's a shared online service of hosting, I can not tell you that with total certainty

Comment: First check if the port is opening properly (e.g. via `netstat -l`) if it is then try connecting to it via a second PHP test script running on the same server which tries to connect to the newly opened websocket. If that works then you can be fairly confident that the issue is due to a firewall.

Comment: @apokryfos I wasn't able to find anything related to this. When i tried `netstat -l` on the SSH I got a buch of line with different ports, but nothing related to 8000. The closest was a tcp on 8649.

Comment: Websockets have to connect through an IP and not a domain as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @SeinopSys I already tried connecting via the IP as well, but also keep getting the same error: `failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Comment: If it's not in your netstat then perhaps there is some sort of configuration on the server which is preventing the creation of the socket. Check if there's any PHP errors thrown that might indicate something.

Comment: @apokryfos I think the actual problem was due to a limit with the server. Since it's a shared hosting, it seems it can't handle WebSockets connections due to security purpouses... The HelpCenter told me to try it with a VPS and it will problaby work.